# How to transfer/recreate users, domain, active directory settings etc from Windows Server 2003 SBS to 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, migration

This is the first time I'm doing such a job so, I will greatly appreciate any detail instructions/steps please.

As the title say, how do I transfer OR recreate(from a scratch) users, domain, active directory etc settings and configuration from Windows Server 2003 SBS to a new 2008 R2 Enterprise, please.

The setup: Standalone Endian firewall, Windows Server 2003 Small Business Server & eight desktops(mix of XP & Win 7). New Server, 2008 R2 is up n running and have been fully updated. 2008 R2 is installed on RAID-1 drive and data will be on RAID-6 drive, configured & managed by hardware RAID controller(Perc H700).

Answer (score 4):

What you should do to "transfer settings" is join the 2008 R2 box to the existing domain. This is what Active Directory is designed to do. Here is a basic outline:

- Set the 2008 R2 box to use the 2003 SBS as its DNS server
- Add the Active Directory Domain Services role on 2008 R2
- Run DCPROMO.exe on the 2003 SBS box and make sure you are adding it as an additional domain controller (DON'T INSTALL DNS YET)
- A few reboots later your domain is now replicated across the 2008 and 2003 SBS boxes
- Now install the DNS role (and DHCP if you need it) and make sure it is AD-integrated
- [Transfer the FSMO roles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324801) to the new domain controller

Do not retire the old 2003 SBS box unless you absolutely have to do so, as Active Directory is not meant to have a single point of failure. One reason to dump the 2003 SBS box would be that you need a specific feature from a 2008 R2-level forest or domain (highly unlikely, but the 2003 SBS can't do any higher level domain than 2003). A better alternative is to demote out the 2003 SBS box using DCPROMO.exe again, upgrade the OS, then rejoin it as a new "third" domain controller.

Comment: Now the main reason to put a new server is to get rid off old one, as there were hard drive, network card etc failures and have no RAID at all. Now the question I was gonna ask after I'm done with server migration is, that at a second physical location we're going to put 2nd 2008 R2, so, how could I backup each other's (1st to 2nd and vice versa) data and may be settings/config too?

Comment: Ohh I totally forgot to mention that, along with Server 2008 R2, we're replacing all eight desktops too. All new desktops are going to be Windows 7 Professional. So would it be better to start from scratch? In that case where/what should I start with(on a new server)?